# how to load .dyn_o in ghci 7.8?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I asked this on haskell-cafe, but there are no responses yet so maybe not enough people are using 7.8.  Perhaps more people are reading stack overflow nowadays:

I recently upgraded to 7.8.2 and I have a silly question.  How do you
get ghci to load compiled modules?  When I try this:

```
% cat >T.hs
module T where

x :: Int
x = 42
% ghc -c -dynamic-too T.hs
% s
T.dyn_hi  T.dyn_o   T.hi      T.hs      T.o
% ghci
GHCi, version 7.8.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package filepath-1.3.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :l T
[1 of 1] Compiling T                ( T.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: T.
*T>
```

It still loads the file interpreted, even though there is a .dyn_o
present.  What am I doing wrong?

This is on x86-64 OS X.

There is one other thing which may be related.  Since I load everything interpreted now, I've noticed that the input gets very laggy when I have a hundred or so modules loaded.  Also the haskeline state gets confused, e.g. I hit escape k to get the previous line, but then it spontaneously goes back into insert mode again.  It stays balky and awkward for about 15 seconds before returning to normal slightly.  It's almost as if, after loading all the bytecode, it's still doing tons of work in the background, with constant GC freezes.  But what work could it be doing?  The bytecode is loaded and I haven't asked it to do anything yet!  I don't know if this is new to 7.8, or if it's a result of loading bytecode instead of binary.

Comment: If I start `ghci` with `-fobject-code`, it loads the existing files. This is on windows so it may not work on osx.

Comment: Indeed that works, but it works by recompiling everything on the spot, it's still not loading dyn_o.  So if you have 200 modules it takes quite a while!  Interestingly, it mostly clears up the input lag, but not entirely.  So there's still some kind of regression from 7.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a known ghc bug:

https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8736

The fix is to compile with -dynamic, not -dynamic-too.